# GroupBy query with Querydsl and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have two entities, one is `Client` and the other is `Transactions` and they are linked `@OneToMany` respectively.

I would like to create a query using Querydsl that will filter my clients based on the count of their transactions. Basically I want this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE id IN (SELECT client_id
FROM (SELECT client_id, count(client_id) as 'count' from transaction group by client_id) as t
where t.count >= 10)
```

to be done in Querydsl. The problem is I want to return a `BooleanExpression` so I can aggregate the query further, i.e `AND` it or `OR` it with some other query.

The Querydsl entities are `QClient` and `QTransaction` respectively.

This is my current code,

```
    QClient client = QClient.client1;
    QTransaction transaction = QTransaction.transaction;
    var count = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "count");
    var subquery = JPAExpressions.select(transaction.client.id, transaction.client.id.count().as(count))
        .from(transaction).groupBy(transaction.client.id).where(count.gt(depositCount)).select(transaction.client.id);
    return client.id.in(subquery);
```

It doesn't work in this form.

Comment: Can you explain `It doesn't work in this form` part. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Also it sounds like you want a part of the sql to be reusable.. and you want to express that in BooleanExpression? is that correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I want it in BooleanExpression because I will combine it with other expressions. I am getting an error: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '>' near line 5, column 13`

Comment: Can you describe which part of the query you want to be as BooleanExpression?

Comment: Basically the entire query, ideally this would return a Client table where I could then further query it by selecting a client by status like this code ```return client.status.id.eq(value);```, or select clients by Country, etc..

Comment: The `client.status.id.eq(value)` is another BooleanExpression that I have, and I could have `N` BooleanExpressions like this, which could be `AND`-ed to give me more complex queries.

Comment: based on your error message.. it looks a bad sql query is generated. Can you show the full picture? like the generated query and the other BooleanExpressions that you used to create the final query?

Comment: Can we chat on this further? It is difficult for me to post error messages and code on comments?

Comment: You can edit your question and post more info. I'm at work and might not be available for chat.

Comment: See my answer below. I've tables User and Article similar to Client and Transactions respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about this?**

Note this is in context to my test project at `https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-web-application-seed`. But you can easily apply the same for your tables.

Ref: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-web-application-seed/blob/master/main-app/src/main/java/gt/app/modules/article/ArticleRepositoryCustomImpl.java#L48

```
    public void doQuery() {
        QArticle qArticle = QArticle.article;
        QUser user = QUser.user;

        var subquery1 = JPAExpressions
            .select(qArticle.createdByUser.id)
            .from(qArticle)
            .groupBy(qArticle.createdByUser.id)
            .having(qArticle.id.count().gt(5));

        BooleanExpression exp = user.id.in(subquery1);

        BooleanExpression exp2 = qArticle.title.length().lt(15);

        List<Article> ar = from(qArticle)
            .join(user).on(qArticle.createdByUser.id.eq(user.id))
            .select(qArticle)
            .where(exp.and(exp2))
            .fetch();

        System.out.println(ar);
    }
```

---

**Also, your query can be simplified.**

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE id IN 
( SELECT client_id FROM 
        (SELECT client_id, count(client_id) as 'count' from ransaction group by client_id)
 as t where t.count >= 10)
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM client
WHERE id IN ( SELECT client_id
            FROM
                TRANSACTION
            GROUP BY
                client_id
            HAVING
                count(client_id)> 10)
```

Comment: Thank you, the `having` clause solved my issue. It appears the alias did not work well, I should investigate it further.